# Instant previewing of your document

Tags: r, latex, rendering, rstudio, r-markdown

Is there an adding, package, or similar for an instant (real-time) rendering of Rmarkdown code? I would prefer using Rstudio, but other GUIs would work too.

I know, e.g., [editR](https://github.com/swarm-lab/editR) aims to achieve this, but has some bugs and does not support some basic Latex code (e.g. new line "\" or "\n"). Otherwise, it is a promising contribution.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't there an option in Rstudio to render code chunk?

Comment: Not sure how rendering a code chunk answers my question. Please explain. What I am looking for is what many Latex editors would have (raw code on the left-hand side of a window, and the instant rendering on the right-hand side)